# I am looking for a PHP script to cause memory leak

Tags: php

can anyone please share some php line that would cause PHP memory to be completely used? I am trying to test something on my site but no matter how many plugins in Wordpress I am running as it's a test site I am not able to exhaust all the memory, not even if I run scans and the php memory limit is set to 18MB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$arr = array();
while (1) {
    $arr[] = rand();
}
```